# How to share link (or image) with quote to a Facebook Page managed by the user in a Flutter app via Facebook mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, flutter, share

I have a Flutter app with some news, and should create a Facebook share button, which can:

- share an image with text
- If Facebook app is installed on the phone, user should be able to login automaticly, and share the content to Facebook on its own News Feed or on whichever Facebook Page managed by the user.

I created a webpage to show the image and content by id, so I got an url to share.
I tried these packages:

- flutter_share_me
- social_share_plugin

And a bunch of others, but the user cannot share on his/her Facebook Page via the Facebook app.

```
if(Platform.isAndroid){
   FlutterShareMe().shareToFacebook(url: url, msg: body);
} else {
   SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebookLink(quote: body, url: url);
}
```

I tried the url_launcher package also:

```
var fbSharer = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodedUrl+'&quote='+ encodedQuote;
launch(fbSharer,forceWebView: false);
```

But in this case the user will be redirected to a browser and should login again to facebook. (After that  the user can share the content to every managed page.)

Is there any option or workaround to fulfill my requirements?

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a flutter package for that. Look into https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me
You can use it to share to Facebook, WhatsApp(WhatsAppBusiness), Twitter And System Share UI. Support Url and Text.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it. I currently use the flutter_share_me package, but in this case the user cannot share the content to Facebook Page via the Facebook App (just to the news feed).